# Getting errors from Monaco editor

Tags: javascript, error-handling, event-listener, monaco-editor

I would like to get hold of the errors created by default by Monaco editor.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can call [`monaco.editor.getModelMarkers({})`](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/monaco.d.ts#L846) to get the list of all markers in the document, and then filter that yourself to limit it to the errors you're interested in. I would prefer a more clearly-documented route, but in my ad-hoc testing this works.

Answer (score 4):

Given a monaco model, you can have access to the worker. This is similar to a ts.LanguageService but the signatures are async. With that you can then call getSemanticDiagnostics() and all the rest.

```
monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker()
  .then(_worker=>{_worker(model.uri)
  .then(worker=>{

    worker.getScriptFileNames().then(ff=>{
      ff.forEach(sf=>{
        worker.getSemanticDiagnostics(sf).then(dd=>{          
          console.log('\n\n DIAGNOSTICS FOR '+sf)
          console.log(dd.map(d=>d.messageText))})
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple sample to log errors:

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'

// ...

monaco.editor.onDidChangeMarkers(([uri]) => {
  const markers = monaco.editor.getModelMarkers({resource: uri})
  console.log('markers:', markers.map(
    ({ message, startLineNumber, startColumn, endLineNumber, endColumn }) =>
      `${message} [${startLineNumber}:${startColumn}-${endLineNumber}:${endColumn}]`,
  ))
})
```

Comment: As of Oct 2022 this works with @monaco-editor/react, but TS is NOT happy with it.